# How to export / import registered user in FusionAuth

Tags: fusionauth

I would like to move my FusionAuth MySQL DB from host a to host b. The MySQL DB is mariaDB 10.1.39

I exported the DB using phpMyAdmin export function and imported it on host b using phpMyAdmin import.
The FusionAuth state using the new DB on host b is as follows:
- Tenants, Applications, API-Keys, certificated, smtp setting, template setting and administrator account are preserved.
- No registered User from the origin DB is available.

What do I need to consider to be able to migrate registered users from FusionAuth location a to location b?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a complete MySQL dump and restore that to the new database server, all of the registered users will be in the new database. My guess is that your export from phpMyAdmin wasn't complete somehow. You can verify this by connecting to the database on host A and issuing this select:

```
select count(*) from users;
```

Then connect the database on host B and issue the same statement. If the numbers aren't identical, then the users did not get copied from host A to host B.

The method I use to export a database and then restore it is using the `mysqldump` command on the command-line. This process looks something like this:

```
$ mysqldump -h host-a -u user -p password --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --result-file=dump.sql fusionauth
$ mysql -h host-b -u user -p password fusionauth < dump.sql
```

This will make a complete backup of the database on host A and then restore it to an empty database/schema on host B.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with the search index - 
https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/130

You have to go to system > reindex to make the users searchable in the App.

I had the same issue (have!):
[I am unable to backup and restore FusionAuth database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58381745/i-am-unable-to-backup-and-restore-fusionauth-database)

So I need to rebuild the index (which throws another error) but at least it appears that the database is indeed being backed up and restored, so that's probably not the issue you have.